# Advice on what FS to use

Tags: ext4, fat32, ext3

I am installing a 2TB drive on an Ubuntu server that will be accessible on a network of Windows and Ubuntu machines. Should I format it using FAT32 or EXT3/4?

Thanks

David C

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason, go with the default, ext4.

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` folder of Ubuntu **should be** ext, it can be `ext`, `ext2`, `ext3`, or `ext4`, but better off stick with `ext4`.

However, you will be able to read and write data to FAT32 or NTFS or ext partitions, so you just need your `/` partitions(analogous to the C: drive for windows) to be ext.

Answer (score 1):

Ext4 is preferred. It has better performance than ext3, and FAT32 is not a journaled filesystem, so is at higher risk of data loss.

The way you share it (i.e. NFS, Samba/CIFS) should abstract the filesystem itself, allowing a Windows system to interact with it, even though Windows doesn't natively handle ext4.